# my web.xml does not know taglib tag

Tags: java, web.xml, taglib, struts-1

I want to use html tags in my jsp, so I have to add the tag lib in web.xml
when I add these lines to web.xml:

```
<taglib>
    <taglib-uri>/tags/struts-html</taglib-uri>
    <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld</taglib-location>
</taglib>
```

it does not know  taglib tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<taglib>` tags must be inside the `<jsp-config>` tag.

But using `Struts2`, you absolutely don't need `struts-html` taglib, it is from Struts 1, which is older, and *completely* different.

Just take a tour of `Struts2` features, and you will discover you don't have to use html-tags anymore, luckily.

Answer (score 5):

Newer versions of the JSP/Servlet containers do not require the taglib entry in the `web.xml` since containers will automatically find it.

You only need the `<%@ taglib %>` directive in your JSP page for using .tld files:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="html" uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to configure the tag-library.

1. **Manual Configuration throw `web.xml`:** Make sure **tld** files are copy to `WEB-INF` folder, configure them in `web.xml` as follow, use the taglib directive attributete in a taglib directive as `<%@ taglib uri="mytagliburi" prefix="ww" %>`.

.

```
<taglib>
         <taglib-uri>mytagliburi</taglib-uri>
         <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld</taglib-location>
</taglib>
```

2. **Manual Configuration only with `taglib` directive**:  Make sure **tld** files are copy to `WEB-INF` folder, and configure the directly in taglib directory as `<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld" prefix="ww" %>`.
3. **Automatic Configuration:** This is the easy way, and used in Struts version 1.2., , just include the `struts-taglib.jar` in your project `classpath` or copy it to `WEB-INF/lib` folder. All the `tld` details are define inside the `struts-taglib.jar\META-INF\tld` folder. During deployment, all tlds will deploy automatically.  However, we can access it via `pre-fixed uri` name only. In this method, we are not allow to change the `taglib uri` name.